# Session object not specified in Tensorflow MNIST tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

Why is there no Session object in the Tensorflow Layers tutorial? Is it possible to obtain it in some way?

Tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

Source code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py

In further development, the session object might be needed to save the trained model, for instance:

```
session = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# some processing here

saver.save(session, 'myModel',global_step=1000)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [TensorFlow `tf.layers` tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) uses [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) as a high-level API that hides the details of constructing a session, and writing a training loop that checkpoints your model and logs summaries. Instead, you specify an `input_fn` that describes your input data and a `model_fn` that describes the layer structure.

If you prefer to use the `tf.Session` (or `tf.train.MonitoredSession`) API directly, you can invoke the `model_fn` directly in your own code and create an optimizer, saver, etc. as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question referred to saving the model, but it seems to be automatically done with `Estimator` class, as you pointed out. To load it later, it turns out that I just needed to define it: `learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="./model")` and that's it.